# Why is the government formed around a representative people party and not around a problems/improvements priority system?

Tags: government, direct-democracy

Why isn't there a government system that uses the majority voting system against problems/ideas that need to be addressed within a society, e.g. having referendums on every vote. The point of this is to eliminate the need to vote for a political party and a person (president/representative) that advertise an agenda of what they think needs fixing and what they propose to do, because this has high chances of corruption, manipulation, false promises, bribery, etc.

Comment: Not a dupe, my answer is the same as to https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/26498/what-is-the-biggest-flaw-with-this-democratic-taxation-system/26499#26499 "People don't do details"

Comment: Comments deleted. Please remember that [the purpose of comments on questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) is to improve the question. They are not for answering the question or for debating its subject matter.

Comment: Are you asking why direct democracy is less common than representative democracy?

Answer (score 1):

### [There Is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_meeting)

The ["Town Meeting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_meeting) (note the distinction between this and a Town *Hall* Meeting) is precisely what you describe.  As someone who grew up in (and still lives in) New England, where such things still exist in the wild, they are largely considered a relic of historical naivete - because they can take FOREVER to make even the simplest decisions.

I'm going to leave aside your claims that party or candidate elections are more prone to corruption than, say: public contractors are - because I don't think the evidence supports the claim and so that becomes its own question.

### Legislatures are Deliberative Bodies

Members of a legislature aren't just deciding issues brought to them by the public. Most often they're exploring issues on their own initiative and in many systems also take an oversight/management role in relation to other branches of government.  This has huge advantages for the voter as they are able to delegate these roles to their MP/MCs.

When issues are presented, it's not just a matter of voting for an answer to the issue, either. Legislative work involves deep exploration of potential solutions, negotiation to achieve a coalition if not consensus, and (ideally) extensive debate so as to arrive at an educated answer.

Moreover, collecting 535 votes (in the US, for example) is a helluva lot easier and cheaper than collecting 345 *million* votes, no matter the system by which votes are tallied. Having to collect hundreds of millions of votes, dozens of times per day would seriously bog down the whole of the system.  Any given issue would therefore only have alert stakeholders voting, and you'd get all sorts of distortions in the results anyway.

### Judges and Executives are Basically Contractors

The reasons are different, but similar, for elected judicial and executive officials (Prime Ministers/Presidents, Justices, etc.): Even in the Town Meeting system of municipal government, the Town will hire someone else to actually do the work, and frequently will hire a Town Manager to play the role of chief executive and ensure that the decisions arrived at via the Town Meeting are swiftly and efficiently carried out.

This is bureaucratic work, "how," "when," and "where," rather than "if" or "why."  Consequently it doesn't translate into the realm of direct democracy at all. So general elections for such officials are already a form of direct democracy where the issue on the table is "Who do we hire do make sure this stuff gets done?"

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is efficiency.  The government is running (almost) every (working) day of the year, and are constantly creating, voting on, passing, and executing bills.  To use an American example, the case of Bush v. Gore (an example of direct democracy) took almost a month and a half to resolve, including recounts, re-recounts, re-re-recounts, "hanging chads", and eventually an appeal to the Supreme Court.  A system which allows this, even in the most outlier-ish of outlier cases, is not feasible, which is why direct democracy is not a serious thing that any jurisdiction in the world actually does at scale.

The second problem is that you're putting the cart before the horse.  You assume a priori that there is a docket, i.e. a list of things that is agreed upon to need to be voted on.  In the example of an indirect democracy, creating the docket is relatively straightforward; you have 500-ish people (in the USA) who submit ideas.  These 500-ish people are expected to have done their homework and only submit ideas which are actually good ideas ("good" defined as "actually issues worthy of debate", as opposed to hypotheticals, edge-cases, or other time-wasters; moral judgments of "good" explicitly not included).  If you have a couple people who submit crappy ideas, that's only a couple people and they can easily be dealt with e.g. via censuring boards, or simply by ignoring them.  Again, this can't be done at scale.

And even if it could, how do you get someone to review those issues and determine how they are tabled?  In the US system (as I understand it), there is a vote on each bill to determine if that bill gets a vote (yes, there is a vote on whether or not to have a vote).  If you put that in a direct democracy system, now every suggestion put forward has to have 2 votes rather than just 1.  If there is a governing board to determine what issues get tabled, to "streamline" this structure, now that governing board is itself a form of indirect democracy (at best, or a dictatorship at worst; issues which don't align with "the party agenda" simply don't get tabled for a vote).

Remember that the number of issues that get tabled scales up with the number of people, while the efficiency at which they get handled scales down with the number of people; the more idea-generators you have, the more ideas you get, while the more voters you have, the less efficient the voting system.  Meaning that, as population grows at scale, you get more things to vote on, and voting on them gets progressively more difficult, to the point at which you eventually wind up with legislative gridlock.  To put this into some (fake) numbers:

Let's say you have 350M people (the population of the US).  Let's say each person has 1 idea per week (this is a significant underestimate, the real answer is likely 1 per waking hour, especially among activist-minded people).  That works out to 50M issues per day.  That means 100M votes per day (as above, 2 votes per issue), or roughly 1,157 votes per second, every second of every day, 24/7/365.  That system is simply not feasible.

The third question is as to whether or not such a system is actually good for people.  The thing about career politicians is, they are, without exception, opportunists.  First and foremost in the mind of any career politician is how they can win the next election, so they can continue to have a job; if they don't win the election, they don't get a paycheque.  Now, if you went to a career politician and said something plainly idiotic, they would say "ok, but also that idea is stupid and implementing it, or even tabling the issue, would hurt my poll numbers, therefore I won't do it".  This hurts sometimes, because the representative is the ultimate arbiter of what is a good or bad issue, and if you have a good issue but the rep doesn't agree with it then it won't get tabled.  However, it also helps sometimes because idiotic ideas which are plainly bad for society will never get heard or voted on.  In short, it is important that if you re a complete doofus, then your opinion is not taken seriously.  Such issues include things like, "what if we nuked Russia over Ukraine", or "what if we cut China off of all trade due to covid" or "what if we completely dismantled all branches of law enforcement over George Floyd"; these aren't pie in the sky hypothetical ideas that only a true nutcase would consider, they are real ideas that real, coherent people discuss (or have discussed in the past) on a regular basis.